# How do most banks handle authorization voids?

Tags: payment, payment-gateway, authorize.net, voiding

There's a lot of outdated information around the web discussing how banks handle a void on a credit card authorization. What I know is still true is that it is the bank's discretion whether (and when) to release their hold on funds or credit line from the authorization. My question is what the most common approach banks (at least in the United States) take with this?

Older sources indicate that most banks will ignore a request to release an authorization, while newer sources seem to be more optimistic about banks releasing funds, but I've not seen any data or explicit statements about a change. I would love to see some actual numbers around this, but experience by anybody operating larger stores would be useful too.

*Note that this is question is not specific to Magento. I'm asking here since it's the most specifically e-commerce-related community on StackExchange.*

Comment: Hi again. -What you're asking about is called an auth reversal. There's some discussion about it wrt Authorize.Net specifically here, although it's quite dated and I'm not clear whether the given answer is even correct. My impression is Authorize.Net still does not support them for the most part. I can't speak to any other gateways or processors. https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/How-to-do-Authorization-Reversals/td-p/5122

Comment: Thanks. That's one of the sources I had found. At five years old I wasn't sure how accurate it still was.